# Submit Open Graph to Facebook (Like)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, submission

I just implemented a like function into my app, where user click on 'Heart' in our app, and it will show on the user's timeline.

So far so good, until I am sending in for approval.

Facebook rejected me few times, saying the Like is not working (not showing on timeline). I had tested on my various test user, none have problem.

During submission form, there is a button call "Add Items to this Submission", click it and it will show you a list of actions and permissions that need to submit. In previous submission, I picked 'Like' and got rejected, and today, I realise there is 1 more permission call 'publish_actions' also require approval.

In my app, I do request 'publish_actions' to send Likes, and it is proven working on all my testers. But on Facebook side, I am not sure if they have special testing tool, where it will ignore whatever permissions you set in your app, and only see for the permissions you submitted.

So if I am submitting Like, is not enough? Must submit 'publish_actions' too? Any facebook engineer or experience people can answer this?

(of course I can try to submit and see if Facebook approve/reject, but hope this knowledge can help people in the future)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: If only [my favorite company] provides decent support, I would not post here. This is the closest platform that can solve this kind of issue, with like minded and high chances of getting reply from community and people with similar experience.

Comment: "No where else to go" is not in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got approval from Facebook.

This is what they want, which is totally not mentioned and out of common sense.

What I assume a submission would be, is to provide only your app and instructions, and assume Facebook has a special account that can bypass any permissions/restriction. The truth is, they are just using a normal account like your's and mine.

Certain feature, like explicit-shared, can only be used after approval, which means, a normal account like yours/mine and the one by Facebook tester will not be able to use, thus failed, and I got rejected.

The solution, is to provide a Test User. Test User can be created in the Role tab, which has ability to use any permission without approval. So when you submit, attach your test user in there. Hope this information can help people out there. I wasted 10 f*** days and 8 submissions to find out.

Comment: Insightful.  I am trying to get an app which can query Page Insights.  I submitted my App and they rejected it.  I think it was because the account they used did not have any "Pages" associated with it.  So I presume I must create a Test account and then instruct them to use this account.

Answer (score 0):

When they made the change to the version of Open Graph 2.0, they moved around a bit what you need to do to, and what needs approval and what doesn't.

I can't seem to find the documentation where I read this, but I believe that yes, your problem is that the users "don't have" publish_actions permission, and that is causing the rejection.

Submit it for approval, it's a quite simple and easy going review process, you will probably pass it with flying colors.

Comment: They just rejected my submission again. This time, I added a native popup, and show the error on the screen. Fb tester copy the error and return back to me. Apparently, is because I am using explicit_shared feature, which require approval. I thought Facebook themselves will have tester who can bypass every permission problem...